# SQL - phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

**TASK:**
Return the mean values of PM2.5 (particulate matter <2.5 micron diameter) & VPM2.5 (volatile particulate matter <2.5 micron diameter) by each station for the year 2019 for readings taken on or near 08:00 hours (peak traffic intensity).
Extend the previous query to show these values for all stations in the years 2010 to 2019.

**MY CODE:**

```
SELECT AVG(`vpm2.5`), AVG(`pm2.5`) FROM `readings`
WHERE 
    DATE (`datetime`) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    AND TIME (`datetime`) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '09:00:00' IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT `station_id-fk` FROM `readings` )
```

could you please let me know what will be the right format ?
at the moment it seems that when I run my code the syntax is right but I am not getting any results
(i am using PHPMyAdmin and the database is there as well)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and update your question with a schema and some sample data, together with expected results.
I'm not sure what the "IN(select...)" is doing though; that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Try to debug your query. First, try to get some results, relax the "where" clause, for example using a wider data range, or even removing the conditions at all.

Comment: Try removing your IN clause and adding a [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) clause and see how far you can get.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did that and it works! My issue now is about the traffic intensity (calculation)... any ideas ?  Thanks a lot for your time